# Route in react, navigate between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't understand how to navigate/route between pages.
I develop a ecommerce website, in first page I have images, I want for each image clicked a new and different page opened and again.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homes />}></Route>
          <Route path="products" element={<Products />}>
            <Route path="women" element={<Women />} >
              <Route path="men" element={<Men />} />
              <Route path="children" element={<Children />} />
              <Route path=":id" element={<???? />} /> 
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export default function Homes () {
  return (
    <div>
      <DetailProduct />
      <Women />
      <Men />
      <Children />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know if `DetailProduct` need to be here

```
export default function Products() {
  return (
    <div className="products">
      <div className="productsNav">
        <Link to="/products/women"></Link>
        <Link to="/products/men"></Link>
        <Link to="/products/children"></Link>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- home-> women -> skirt -> detailProducts
- home-> women -> jeans -> detailProducts
- home-> men -> pants -> detailProducts

In home i have women,men,chidren images when i clicked in women a new page opened with skirt and when i clicked in skirt new page opened with detailProduct. Same for each category in the home page.

For "women" I want it open page with all the skirt and for jeans another page with all the jeans `<Route path=":id" element={<skirt />} />` but I have another element {`<jeans />`} how fix that?

For "men" another page `<Route path=":id" element={<pants />} />`.

I don't know how do for detailProduct, for each skirt I want open a new page with the detail of skirt, same for jeans and same for all the items for men and children.

Comment: I think you first need to nail down what you actually want your routes to be before you add your links, e.g. to know what you link to. You have your `Men` and `Children` routes nested under the `Women` route, e.g. `"/products/women/men"`. Can you [edit] to clarify your route organization first, and *then* if you still need help linking correctly we can help.

Comment: * home-> women -> skirt -> detailProducts
* home-> women -> jeans -> detailProducts
* home-> men -> pants -> detailProducts

In home i have women,men,chidren images when i clicked in women a new page opened with skirt and when i clicked in skirt new page opened with detailProduct. Same for each category in the home page.

Comment: Is `Home` rendering the same `Men`, `Women`, and `Children` components that you are rendering on the routes? What is "detailProducts"? Is this the same component for each of `"/products/(men|women|children)/:id"`, e.g. `<Route path=":id" element={<ProductDetails />} />` where the `id` param is used to load the correct product? Can you include these routed components for a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Morning!
it's similar to anchor tag of html. You have to import Link, inside of the react-router-dom library as the example below:
`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`

And after use as next example below:
`<Link to={'/products'}> <img /> </Link>`